# selecting different record for each user at the same time using MSSQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My web application has approximate 300 users when they fetch the next record on the same time I want to display them record so that each user have different record (i.e its not repeated between them)

And also fetched records want to mark them as fetched so it should not be consider in next fetch lot.

I don't know whether following query will work for me or not.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Table_name] ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Comment: `select top 1 * from MyTable where Fetched=0 order by newid()` to prevent already fetched records to appear. And then you'll have to mark fetched records as fetched `update myTable set Fetched=1`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try

Comment: obviously for the update you need to specify id of the record that you are working with. Currently this statement will update all the records in the table with `fetched=1`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to `ORDER BY` something - just use `TOP 1` - the SQL Engine will order by the rows by itself (using index for example):

```
BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @TableId INT;

Select top 1 @TableId = TableId
from MyTable
where Fetched=0;

Update myTable 
set Fetched=1 
WHERE TableId = @TableId;

COMMIT TRAN;

SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE TableId = @TableId;
```

You can wrapped the whole statement in transaction and check the [isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql) level of your database - you can change the isolation level in your stored procedure, too.

Comment: While update should I need to consider the "with or without lock" statement

Comment: You can wrapped the whole statement in transaction.